# Issue with dictionary in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, dictionary, javascript-objects

Relatively new to React/Javascript in general so any help would be appreciated.

I currently have an application which is fetching data for multiple items from an API. buys is a list of dictionaries(called buy here) with fields asset, units and price (among other things).

```
buys.map(async buy => {
    var data = await queryCoinGeckoAPI(buy);

    var market_price = data.market_data.current_price.aud;
    var price_change = data.market_data.price_change_24h_in_currency.aud;
    var price_change_percentage = data.market_data.price_change_percentage_24h_in_currency.aud;
    var profit = buy.units === 0 || buy.price === 0 ? 0 : market_price * buy.units - buy.price;

    newDictionary[buy.asset] = {
        asset: buy.asset,
        market_price: market_price,
        price_change: price_change,
        price_change_percentage: price_change_percentage,
        profit: profit
    };
});
```

That's all fine and when I come to log newDictionary:

[Hooray it works!](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vtojG.png)

However, the problem comes when I'm not trying to access these values in the dictionary. If I try calling `newDictionary['bitcoin']` or `Object.keys(newDictionary)` or even

```
for(let key in newDictionary) {
    console.log(key);
    console.log(newDictionary[key]);
}
```

for example I get no output.

[Undefined returned](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BmwaC.png)

Not particularly sure why and couldn't find an answer on this online...

I chose a dictionary because I would like to be able to update my current state (I hope this is how you use the spread operator):

```
setBuys(
    buys.map(b => {
        {...b, ...newDictionary[b.asset]};
    })
);
```

Full function in case you need it :

```
useEffect(() => {
    const refreshData = async() => {
        var d = await Promise.all(
            buys.map(async buy => {
                var data = await queryCoinGeckoAPI(buy);

                var market_price = data.market_data.current_price.aud;
                var price_change = data.market_data.price_change_24h_in_currency.aud;
                var price_change_percentage = data.market_data.price_change_percentage_24h_in_currency.aud;
                var profit = buy.units === 0 || buy.price === 0 ? 0 : market_price * buy.units - buy.price;

                return {
                    asset: buy.asset,
                    market_price: market_price,
                    price_change: price_change,
                    price_change_percentage: price_change_percentage,
                    profit: profit
                };
            })
        )

        var newDictionary = {};
        for (let i = 0; i < d.length; i++) {
            newDictionary[d[i].asset] = d[i];
        }

        console.log(newDictionary);
            
        setBuys(
            buys.map(
                b => {
                    {...b, ...newDictionary[b.asset]}
                }
            )
        )

        // toast.info('Market updated', {});
    }
    const interval = setInterval(() => {
        refreshData();
      }, 60000);
    return () => clearInterval(interval);
})
```

Thanks!

Comment: newArray is an object though not an array. So you'd call its properties through dot notation

Comment: I have tried with both `newDictionary['bitcoin']` and `newDictionary.bitcoin`, both are still returning undefined.

Comment: For one, your code is not awaiting for all of the queries to finish before it does the `set`. You also can't `.map` over a dictionary.

Comment: I would recommend separating your user-entered data (units, buy price) from the data you fetch from CoinGecko; that way you don't need to worry about merging the objects in your fetch. Also, `profit` is really just a calculated value that you shouldn't likely compute in advance.

Comment: @AKX, I don't believe I'm using `.map` on a dictionary. `buys` is an array of dictionaries. In terms of the the await stuff, does my code not go over every asset and await a response before I call `set`? If not how do I guarantee it? My understanding is that since the `set` is called after the `map` which had the await, I would be guaranteed to have finished before setting.

Comment: Fair – it's hard to tell since you're not showing the code that initializes `buys` to begin with. :) Anyway, `.map` and `.forEach` etc. are unaware of `await`s within the functions; the usual pattern is `await Promise.all(things.map(async function() { ... }))` so you `await` for all of the promises returned by the async function to resolve.

Comment: Thanks for your help, I'll try the Promise.All thing and see how that goes.

Comment: @AKX, thanks for your help it worked a treat. I was just wondering if you knew how to fix my spread operation or had a guide where I could learn?

Comment: @foo.d Sure. Could you update your current working code into the question?

Comment: @AKX, i've updated my code now thanks (I'll fix the profit and things you said later ;))

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem with your final `setBuys` call is that you're simply not returning anything from the mapper function since it's using `{}` braces.

You'll want

```
setBuys(
  buys.map(
    b => (
      {...b, ...newDictionary[b.asset]}
    )
  )
)
```

instead (`b => (`, not `b => {`).

Answer (score 0):

> (I'm not even sure if dictionaries are a thing in React).

You are probably thinking of objects, perhaps that can help you with googling anything related in the future.

I think the spread operator is the culprit here, try replacing it with this (forgive the formatting):
`.maps( b => {{b: newArray[b.asset]}}`

Try adding to some log statements to see the acual contents of newArray, maybe it is actualy an object instead of an array.

Comment: Hi @TheElmo, my problem is occurring before I even try to use the spread operator. I'm logging the fields after the fetch but before the map and it's not working.

Comment: In that case, isn't newDictionary a scoped variable? Try defining it outside of the refreshData const